# What setting toggles the automatic creation of End if and End Sub?

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2019 and
vb.Net

I must have changed a setting because when I start an IF statement or a SUB the closing statements of END IF and END SUB are no longer automatically created. I've tried every setting I could think of but no love. Yes I googled but those words are extremely common and I wasn't able to find the appropriate information so if you can help me out that would be lovely.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try this
Click Tool => Options => Text Editor => Basic => Advanced
Under Editor Help, make sure 'Automatic insertion of end constructs' is checked off